# Is jQuery "each()" function synchronous?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

consider this scenario for validating:

```
function validateForm (validCallback) {
   $('#first-name').add($('#last-name')).add($('#address')).each(function () {
      // validating fields and adding 'invalid' class to invalid fields.
   });
   // doing validation this way for almost 50 fields (loop over 50 fields)
   if ($('#holder .invalid').length == 0) {
       // submitting data here, only when all fields are validated.
   }
}
```

Now, my problem is that, the **if** block get executed before loops are finished. I expected the body of `validateForm` to be executed synchronously, but it seems that jQuery `each()` function gets executed asynchronously. Am I right? Why this doesn't work?

Comment: What does the validation code look like? `each` is synchronous, but the code inside might not be...

Comment: `each` itself is processed synchronously. Are you starting some async operation of your own from inside the loop?

Comment: similar problem here .. how did you solve it ?

Comment: It's a long time ago, I can't remember. But I know that the answers helped me. So, I might have used async code blocks in my validation code (like trying to validate address using an ajax request).

Comment: hmm ..i solved it this way.. i was doing "return false" inside each function which was not working i guess.. now am maintaining a flag inside this each function and returning that flag at the end of validation ..

Comment: The problem here was maybe that you declared variables inside function() that were not visible in the if statement?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Yes, the jQuery `each` method is synchronous. Nearly ALL JavaScript is synchronous. The only exceptions are AJAX, timers (`setTimeout` and `setInterval`), and HTML5 Web Workers.
Your problem is probably somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 9):

`jQuery` is purely a javascript library. Except `ajax`, `setTimeout` and `setInterval` there is nothing that can asynchronously executed in `JavaScript`. So `each` is definitely executed synchronously. There is definitely some js error inside the `each` block code. You should take a look in the console for any errors.

Alternatively you can take a look at jQuery [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) to execute any function in the queue. This will make sure the queued function will be executed only when the previous code execution is complete.

Comment: there are also promises... just saying :)

Answer (score 8):

Another reason to ask that question would be that .each will simply stop iteration when the (.each() ) function returns false, and an additional variable must be used to pass the "return false" information.

```
var all_ok=true;
$(selector).each(function(){
    if(!validate($(this))){
        all_ok=false; //this tells the outside world something went wrong
        return false; //this breaks the .each iterations, returning early
    }
});
if(!all_ok){
    alert('something went wrong');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For me it works like asyncronous. If it works sync, why it works like that:

```
var newArray = [];
$.each( oldArray, function (index, value){
        if($.inArray(value["field"], field) === -1){
            newArray.push(value["field"]);
        }
    }
);

//do something with newArray here doesn't work, newArray is not full yet

$.when.apply($, newArray).then(function() {
    //do something with newArray works!! here is full
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`return false` in `.each()` function breaks the loop only, and the remaining code outside the loop still executes. So set a flag in `.each()` loop and check it outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. So i fix like this

```
var y = jQuery(this).find(".extra_fields");
for(var j in y)
{
    if( typeof  y[j] =='object')
    {
        var check = parseInt(jQuery(y[j]).val());
        if(check==0){
            jQuery(y[j]).addClass('js_warning');
            mes="Bạn vui lòng chọn đầy đủ các thuộc tính cho sản phẩm";
            done=false;
            eDialog.alert(mes);
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats how i do it

```
 function getAllEventsIndexFromId(id) {
    var a;
    $.each(allEvents, function(i, val) {
        if (val.id == id) { a=i; }
    });
    return a;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. my $.each was inside the success function of ajax call. i made my ajax call synchronous by adding `async: false` and it worked.

Answer (score -10):

The jQuery.each method loops Synchronously, but you can't guarantee that it'll loop through the items in any specific order.

Comment: No, it'll always loop through them in the order they appear in the document.

Comment: It depends on what you are iterating over. Each guarantees index order execution on an array but makes no guarantees for an object(which should be obvious).