# How to search for an id within a selector?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Inspired by this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501719/dynamically-adding-a-form-to-a-django-formset-with-ajax) I am cloning a set of elements with jquery and renaming the id's accordingly in a .find .each loop to keep them unique.

like this:

```
newElement.find(':input').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + 0 + '-','-' + total + '-');
    var id = 'id_' + name;
    $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

So far so good, my goal is to check a checkbox in there as well that the form was originally cloned.

1) I have two ways to achieve this, I set the checkbox within the selector before renaming of the id's take place.

```
$newElement  ??? -->  $('#id_deals-0-is_form_cloned_by_ajax').prop('checked', true);
```

2) Or I wait until the id's have been renamed and have been made unique:

```
$('#id_deals-' + total + '-is_form_cloned_by_ajax').prop('checked', true);
```

The problem with the second approach is that the .find . each is an asynchronous approach and the renaming might have not taken place by the time I try to look for that checkbox's id to set it.

Hence I thought approach one is safer, but I have no idea how to check for an ID within a selector only.

May anyone point me to the right direction please?

Comment: The find.each isn't asynchronous?

Comment: but each(function() { ... } ) is not async? Are you sure?

Comment: Very sure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371942/is-jquery-each-function-synchronous

Comment: Ahh that's very good to know. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newElement.find(':input').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + 0 + '-','-' + total + '-');
    var id = 'id_' + name;
    $(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('').removeAttr('checked');
});

// Find an element within $newElement
$newElement.find('#id_deals-' + total + '-is_form_cloned_by_ajax').attr('checked', true);
```

Comment: Alright. Since find.each is actually synchronous after all, the second option is the better choice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use .find like you have before to find the ID. Simples?

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: you mean like this? `$newElement.find('#id_deals-0-is_form_cloned_by_ajax').prop('checked', true);`