# How do you call a function once all iterations using .each() has occurred?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Below is a snippet which I need help on. I want to call a function once all the span's have been iterated through. So an example would be if I had 8 spans's, after the 8th span's function has been run, how do I call `nextFunction()`?

```
    $('#div1').animate({ opacity: '0.2' }, 500, function () {
         $('span').each(function () {
             //do something.
         });
         nextFunction();
    });

    function nextFunction() {
         alert("called after the last .each() has occurred");
    };
```

Comment: use the animate callback

Comment: jQuery's [`each` function is synchronous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371942/is-jquery-each-function-synchronous) - there is no additional code needed to perform what you're asking for - are you getting different results?

Comment: Doesn't this work? I was under the impression that `each` was synchronous - `nextFunction` would get called after `each` had completed.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I understand; this code seems to do exactly what you're asking; what is actually happening?

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle, normally it should work.

Comment: @dandavis I believe the OP is already using that callback

Comment: is there any async operation within the each loop

Comment: @ZathrusWriter: yup, my bad. good eye. though it still doesn't make sense since each is sync...

Comment: Isn't the issue that animate isn't synchronous? This will use a setTimeout underneath.

Comment: Are there multiple div1's?

Answer (score 1):

Try [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```
$('#div1').animate({
    opacity: '0.2'
}, 500, function () {  
    $.when($('span').each(function () {
        //do something.
    })).then(function () {
        nextFunction(); 
    });
});

function nextFunction() {
    alert("called after the last .each() has occurred");
};
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: This doesn't accomplish anything. it's essentially identical to what he already has.

Answer (score 1):

The code should actually run sequentially, just the way you have written it, unless you're planning to use AJAX requests in the .each() loop.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$('#div1').animate({ opacity: '0.2' }, 500, function () {
         var doSomething = 0,
             ctx = null,
             checker = null;
         checker = function() {
           if (domSomething === $('span').length)
           {
              clearTimeout(ctx);
              nextFunction();
              return ;
           }
           setTimeout(checker, 100);
         };
         $('span').each(function () {
             doSomething += 1;
             //do something.
         });
         checker();
    });
```

Comment: @Paul erm, thats not pure JS

Answer (score 0):

`.each()` is synchronous. It will work the way you have it. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8V5L2/)