# How to wait all callbacks in each-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have cells with different validators on them. When one cell is validating I need to re-validate other cells of its group. Validation fires on 'blur' event so I have to trigger 'blur' event on all cells in group:

```
element.attr('validated', true);
var validityGroup = getValidityGroupElements();
validityGroup.each(function() {
  $(this).blur();
});
element.attr('validated', false);
```

Here `element` is a current cell and function `getValidityGroupElements()` gives me an array of elements of current group whith `validated="false"` attribute. I'm setting this attribute to avoid infinite-loop when each cell will validate all cells in it's group and so on. But the problem is: how to wait all callbacks which runs in `.each` loop and only after that set the validated attribute of current element to `false`?

Comment: you can simply call `validityGroup.blur()`, no need for the loop, and `validated` is not a valid attribute, use `data-validated` or a `.validated` css class

Comment: You do not need to wait for each to get executed - repeated here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7371983/1270199

Comment: @Aman `each` is synchronous but `element.attr('validated', false)` executes before the `blur` callbacks fires, thats the problem :(

Comment: @DavidFregoli, if I'm using `validityGroup.blur()` it's still not clear for me is it possible to wait for all callbacks which are fires on `blur` event before change attribute's value. It works if I wrapped `element.attr('validated', false)` in `setTimeout` function but I think it's not a good way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're abusing the `blur` event to trigger the validation which causes problems: In your browser, the "send the `blur` event" is synchronous (so the event is sent right away) but the handler isn't executed at that time. The browser just pushes an event on the stack and then eventually starts to execute them. Since JS doesn't support parallel execution, the first `blur` event will be executed after the code above - i.e. after `validated` has been reset to `false`.

A much better design would be to attach the validation function to the element:

```
e.data('validate', function(){...});
```

In `blur()` and everywhere else, you can now write: `e.data('validate')();` to call the validation function (the double parentheses is not a typo - `e.data('validate')` returns a function).

This will allow you to validate in a well-defined order and synchronously without any events or the `validated` hack.